Error when I try to use flutter in_app_purchase package?
I am try to use 'in_app_purchase' package in my flutter app. I am getting one error.
When I click on Subscribe button, it open a subscribe window like image. Now if close this window by clicking outside of the window or even when I subscribe it, then the of closing the window, the error is thrown on debug console.
I didn't write huge code, just install the package, initialize it and get products then handler. I do not do anything on my android folder.
The error is like the second image.
First Image
Second Image
class _SubscriptionPageState extends State<SubscriptionPage> {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

  //Product Listing
  static const List<String> _productIds = ['com....subscription'];

  Future<Subscription> getProducts() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      return Subscription(
        isAvailable: isAvailable,
        products: [],
        notFoundIds: [],
      );
    }
    final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
        await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_productIds.toSet());

    if (productDetailResponse.error != null) {
      throw Exception(productDetailResponse.error!.message);
    }
    return Subscription(
      isAvailable: isAvailable,
      products: productDetailResponse.productDetails,
      notFoundIds: productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: QueryBuilder(
        query: Query(
          key: ['subscription'],
          queryFn: () => getProducts(),
          config: QueryConfig(
            storeQuery: false,
            cacheDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ),
        ),
        builder: (context, state) {
          final product = state.data!.products[0];
          return BasicAppButton(
            title: 'Subscribe',
            onPressed: () {
              final PurchaseParam param = GooglePlayPurchaseParam(
                productDetails: product,
                changeSubscriptionParam: null,
              );
              _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(
                purchaseParam: param,
              );
            },
            level: '3',
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

